# 27 hours layover in Dubai and no valid visa

Tags: visas, dubai, filipino-citizens

I will be going home from Egypt to Philippines on Oct 21 to 23 with layover in Dubai on Oct 22 for almost 27 hours. Online visa application was no longer available since I logged the request late. Will I be able allowed to stay at Dubai airport for the whole layover even without visa?

Comment: If you didn't create the 27 hours gap yourself by manually booking two different flights, then there should be nothing to be worried about: the airline company wouldn't have issued the ticked, in case. You can always get a transit visa on arrival at the airport, anyway. All very very IMHO.

Comment: There is a hotel airside at DXB so you wouldn't necessarily have to pass through immigration. http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/dubai_international_airport/emirates_terminal_3/airport_hotel.aspx The link in Moo's answer below though suggests that you'll need a transit visa because your layover is more than 24 hours.

Answer (score 11):

According to Emirates and its [visa checker](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=PH&NV=Philippines&DC=PH&DV=Philippines&TC=AE&TV=United%20Arab%20Emirates&h=16b68771fcd5f6c82e9ec3629a67d7468cf42ac2), as you are a Philippines national, transiting to the Philippines through the UAE and have a lay over for more than 24 hours, you need a visa regardless of whether you stay in the airport or not.

It does look like there is a transit visa offer available (not an Emirates offer, a UAE offer) where you can receive a 96 hour visa on arrival along with a hotel for the transit period, but I don't know how much that would cost.